# Does flink sends duplicate records if there are multiple downstream operator

Tags: java, apache-flink

If I run an example flink application like below:

```
DataStream ds;
ds.map(new MapFunction1()).print();
ds.map(new MapFunction2()).print();
```

Will flink send **twice** for each records from **ds** to downstream operators(MapFunction1 and MapFunction2) internally?

I know that data exchange in flink is happened in taskmanager level instead of operator level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try:

```
    StreamExecutionEnvironment environment =
            StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataStream<Long> someIntegers = environment.generateSequence(0, 0);
    someIntegers.map(aLong -> aLong + 1).print();
    someIntegers.map(aLong -> aLong + 2).print();

    environment.execute();
```

OutPut:

```
1> 1
1> 2
```

Comment: I know it will output 1 and 2 in your example, what I want to know is if the two downstream map operators are located in different task managers, as the data exchange is happened on task manager level, will there be two output buffers for the source stream or still be one, but two task managers takes the records from the same input buffer?

Answer (score 0):

The job graph for this application looks like this, and the whole application runs in a single thread, in one taskmanager. I disabled operator chaining to get the Flink webui to generate this diagram, but if I hadn't done that, there'd have been no networking involved at all.

[image]

Comment: Suppose the map1 is running in tm#1, map2 is running in tm#2, I image that when any data generated by source written to its "Result Partition", then underneath netty will transfer the data to both tm#1 and tm#2, right? What I am not sure is that who remove the input data from source's "Result Partition" after netty transferred data to both tm completed?